# Include Dynamically Named Files

Tags: php

I'm just curious how I can include a PHP file that doesn't have a static name like home.php, or contacts.php?

I want to have it so when I click on a link it includes the name of the page I was sent to.

So, I click on "Contacts", instead of my code being:

```
<?php include "contacts.php"; ?>
```

It's:

```
<?php include "somekindofcodetohavethisdynamic.php"; ?>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There should be some logic that returns the dynamic stuff, right? Put that into a function:

```
function getDynamicName($page) {
  // Magic happens here.
}
```

And, get it stored in some variable. And include it in the normal way.

```
$contactPage = getDynamicName("contact");
include "{$contactPage}.php";
```

If you are very lazy, you can do this as well:

```
include getDynamicName("contact") . ".php";
```

Comment: Sorry, is this all being included in the "master" file?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. Which master file? @ThomasHutton

Comment: WOW `// Magic happens here.` that's awesome!

Comment: @AbraCadaver How do we know the recipe of the magic sauce when the OP themselves doesn't know it? `:P`

Comment: So, I have my master.php file which is basically the HTML file in which everything is loaded, and called.  And all the necessary includes are in that file (header, footer, etc).

Comment: @ThomasHutton Great... Yea, then it should be in that same file. Wherever you include this, please make sure it is a PHP file and not a HTML one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused in what I do with the function.

Comment: @ThomasHutton How is the dynamic value getting generated?

Comment: By clicking on a hyperlink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132303/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-thomas-hutton).